# CKeditor component with angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I am a newbie in Angular4

I want to integrate CKeditor in Angular4

As i follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor) url but it's for Angular 2 not working in Angular 4.

As i have check there

```
System.config({
"map": {
  "ng2-ckeditor": "npm:ng2-ckeditor",
},
"packages": {
  "ng2-ckeditor": {
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js",
  },
}
});
```

but there is no any option for System.config in Angular 4

Then i have integrated [froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/angularjs-2-4) but it gives licence error and also not allow to configure and i tried but it's not effecting

How can i integrate CKeditor in Angular4?

Comment: what is the error you are you getting ? most often if it fits in A2 , fits in A4 too

Comment: where to set System.config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you use `angular-cli` to create your angular 4 project , you dont need system.config in `angular-clli`, that only used in system.js, and the code you have there is telling system.js where to find the ckeditor module.
in case you not clear, just check whether your project have an 'angular-cli.json' file, if there is, then you can follow the below steps:

1. use `npm install ng2-ckeditor` to install the ng2-ckeditor
2. in your `app.module.ts`, you should have something like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    FormsModule
  ],

  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

and then

3. in your index.html add

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

inside head section. alternatively, you can save the js file inside your project, then insde `.angular-cli.json` file, add the file of that file into `scripts` array

then you are good to use ckeditor in your angular 4 project

Comment: @Nitin I did try it myself and it worked, what errors did you have?

Comment: first i get this error 
"Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ckeditor'"

then if i remove ngModel attr from ckeditor then i got 

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined"

for this i am not able to get the solution

Comment: @Nitin in order to use `ngModel`, you need to import `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms`, I need more details of you code to identity the second issue, or maybe you can check this [repo](https://github.com/lcshan/ngx-ckeditor-template), that's a working template with angular 4 and ckeditor

Comment: i add the script file in agular cli file in script tag

so the dir of undefined error was coming so that has been resoolved

Comment: Thanks it works for me

but have one quetion

as i kept ckeditor lib in my local lib and use it then its not working

and if i use live then it works

if i kept local file path then again it gives me dir error

so have you any idea?

Comment: @Nitin my guess is you got a wrong path of ckeditor file in `angular-cli.json` file, i have updated my [git repo](https://github.com/lcshan/ngx-ckeditor-template) to use a local file to get ckeditor work, hope that help

Comment: you haven't removed the live path from index html

Comment: @Nitin my bad, I didnt save the index.html file when I test it, so I thought it work. According this [post](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/125), looks like you cant bundle ckeditor into webpack, angular-cli is webpack based, and in there is a [ckeditor5](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/139). but I personally use tinymce in my angular 4 projects, its easier to setup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153866/discussion-between-nitin-and-lucas).

Comment: i have implemented the ckeditor and it works for me as of now 

and if you have tinymce steps to integrate then you can share so it can be helpful in future

Comment: @Nitin you can follow the document [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/)

Comment: @Nitin could you please share the steps to integrate CKeditor with local js files for angular 4

Comment: @LaxmanChari please follow the steps which are given and you have to include ckeditor file in index html and then it will work

Comment: Isn't there any way where we can avoid the index.html import? Because the ckeditor script download slows down page load.